# Update Current Url Without Adding in URL

Tags: php

im trying to make my current url to change without adding more information in front of the  url. For example:

Link: http://www.domain.com/jobs.php?id=1

I have ul li  listing links where depending on which link i select the "r" query changes his value, so when i select it gets this result:

Link: http://www.domain.com/jobs.php?id=1&r=10

But when i choose another select option link  the query with the result of "20" for example, instead of updating only the value it adds more info in the url like this:

Link: http://www.domain.com/jobs.php?id=1&r=10&r=20

instead of becoming link this

Link: http://www.domain.com/jobs.php?id=1&r=20

Note:
Is important i use always the current url, because in my page i have many parameters. Like for example the "type of job" is selected or other info and not use

Here is my code:

```
    $currentURL = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $currentURL;?>&r=50">50 km</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $currentURL;?>&r=100">100 km</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $currentURL;?>&r=150">150 km</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use `parseurl` to get the base path of the URL, and then reconstruct the query string as a whole with `http_build_query`. Sorry, don't have time to construct a full answer with sample code or find the links.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're displaying the $currentURL which everytime you click a new link includes the old information.

So the first time you click a link your URL is:

http://www.google.com

However the next time you click the next link your current url is the one above.

http://www.google.com?test=test

Then the next time you click the link once again the current url is the one that you now have (see above) so when you click it again and add on another parameter it retains all the information it previously had - becoming:

http://www.google.com?test=test&test=test

To get around this try to use HTTP_HOST instead - that only gets the base URL address:

```
$currentURL = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];

<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $currentURL;?>?id=1&r=50">50 km</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $currentURL;?>?id=1&r=100">100 km</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $currentURL;?>?id=1&r=150">150 km</a></li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively you could split the $currentURL string on the first instance of the &r - that way the id and any other variables could always be different if needs be.

```
$currentURL = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];;
$URLpieces = explode("&r", $currentURL );
echo $currentURL [0]; // will output everything before &r
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the response @hollie3406 but this way doesnt work, because if i use only the "HTTP_HOST" im loosing the previous parameters of the url, for example if a have a parameter of the "jobtype"

Comment: Ok - can you use the second example, where you split the string? I forgot to add in the REQUEST_URI parameter to that one - so it may work for you now, as long as the &r is at the end of the url string